# Aurelia RoutableComponentActivate implementation

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious, but I can't seem to see what it is.

I really like having the type safety of Typescript and am trying to incorporate that into my Aurelia project, but am running into a bit of a snag.

I have a `LectureDetails.ts` component that looks as follows:

```
import { autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { NavigationInstruction, RouteConfig, RoutableComponentActivate } from 'aurelia-router';
import { ILecture } from './lecture';

@autoinject()
export class LectureDetails implements RoutableComponentActivate {
  lecture: ILecture;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  activate(params: any, routeConfig: RouteConfig, navigationInstruction: NavigationInstruction): Promise<ILecture> {
    return this.http
               .fecth('/api/lectures/1', { method: 'GET' })
               .then(response => response.json())
               .then(lecture => this.lecture = lecture)
               .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

The problem is the Typescript compiler keeps complaining about the `activate` method and I can't figure out how to update it to bring it into compliance.

```
Class 'LectureDetails' incorrectly implements interface 'RoutableComponentActivate'.

Types of property 'activate' are incompatible.

...
```

It looks like the typings file is expecting a return type of `Promise<void> | PromiseLike<void> | IObservable | void`, but I don't know how to update the `fetch/then` methods to be of that type. If I remove the types, the code compiles and runs just fine.

How could I make this method compile and retain the type safety? Why isn't the return type of the `RoutableComponentActivate` method of type `Promise<T>`?

**UPDATE:** It seems as though, if I update the signature to return `Promise<any>` then it will compile. I assume the actual type doesn't matter at that point because it is a method called by the framework/convention and therefore the framework doesn't need to know about the type the promise will return when resolved?

Comment: I think the contract is `Promise<void>` because usually you would do something like `.then(result => { this.someItem = result; })`

Comment: I'm sorry, I seem to have missed that line in my original code dump. I updated the question. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your comment, but even with `.then(lecture => this.lecture = lecture)` I'm still encountering the problem.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps the signature should be changed. The best thing to do is opening an issue in the official repo https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues